# How do I create a circular or elliptical selections in Javascript for use in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, ellipse, photoshop-script

So my end goal is to create 4 circular selections at the corners, but after looking through documentation and having searched many times, I couldn't find information on anything other than rectangular selection areas. I believe there *should* be a solution, but I can't really think of anything that doesn't involve setting up a huge array of boundary pixel locations for a circle (which I'm not even sure would work, as I'm fairly new to Photoshop scripting and how it works).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Photoshop scripting API in not complete and sometimes you will get stuck trying to accomplish certain tasks. A great tool for handling this is Adobe's very own ScriptListener plugin. It will take a little bit of time to figure out the code it spits out but this will help fill the holes with your scripting. Below is a function I use for making circular selections:

```js
function makeCircle(left,top,right,bottom,antiAlias){

var circleSelection = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var descriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id71 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref5 = new ActionReference();
        var id72 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var id73 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
        ref5.putProperty( id72, id73 );
    descriptor.putReference( id71, ref5 );
    var id74 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
        var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();

        var top1 = charIDToTypeID( "Top " );
        var top2 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc12.putUnitDouble( top1, top2, top );

        var left1 = charIDToTypeID( "Left" );
        var left2 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc12.putUnitDouble( left1, left2, left );

        var bottom1 = charIDToTypeID( "Btom" );
        var bottom2 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc12.putUnitDouble( bottom1, bottom2, bottom );

        var right1 = charIDToTypeID( "Rght" );
        var right2 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc12.putUnitDouble( right1, right2, right );

    var id83 = charIDToTypeID( "Elps" );
    descriptor.putObject( id74, id83, desc12 );
    var id84 = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
    descriptor.putBoolean( id84, antiAlias );
executeAction( circleSelection, descriptor, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I'll have to run it a few times and tweak things so that I can fully understand it.