# Photoshop scripting circular selection on new layer

Tags: javascript, geometry, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I'm trying to dynamically add layers in a Photoshop script via JavaScript. The layers have a circular selection, not rectangular or triangular.

For example rectangular:

```
var RectangleSelection = Array(
   Array(x, y), // start position
   Array(x + width, y), // right top
   Array(x + width, y + height), // right bottom
   Array(x, y + height), // left bottom
   Array(x, y) // left top
);
```

I want to do the same now with a circular selection, maybe with a function like this? I'm stuck how to define the function:

```
var circleSelection = makeCircleSelection(x,y,radius);
```

And return it in a selection which I can then place on a new layer:

```
var layer = document.artLayers.add();
document.selection.select(circleSelection);
document.selection.copy();
document.paste();
```

The docs don't have an answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235191/how-do-i-create-a-circular-or-elliptical-selections-in-javascript-for-use-in-pho) I find difficult for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the following custom `makeCircleSelection` function. As you can see its signature has three parameters, namely `x`, `y` and `radius`.

```js
/**
 * Make a circular selection.
 * @param {Number} x The center of the circular selection on the x-axis.
 * @param {Number} y The center of the circular selection on the y-axis.
 * @param {Number} radius The radius of the circular selection.
 * @returns {Object} A reference to the newly created circular selection.
 */
function makeCircleSelection(x, y, radius) {
  var d1 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var d2 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref = new ActionReference();

  d1.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Top '), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), y - radius);
  d1.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Left'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), x - radius);
  d1.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Btom'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), y + radius);
  d1.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Rght'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), x + radius);

  ref.putProperty(charIDToTypeID('Chnl'), charIDToTypeID('fsel'));

  d2.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref);
  d2.putObject(charIDToTypeID('T   '), charIDToTypeID('Elps'), d1);
  d2.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Fthr'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), 0);
  d2.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('AntA'), true);

  executeAction(charIDToTypeID('setd'), d2, DialogModes.NO);
  return document.selection;
}
```

Then you can do the following to meet your requirement:

```js
// Example usage

var document = app.activeDocument;

var circleSelection = makeCircleSelection(200, 100, 100);
circleSelection.copy();

document.artLayers.add();
document.paste();
```

**Note:** You'll need to ensure that pixels exist within the circular selection on the active art layer that you copy from. The area cannot be transparent.